# Lightning Input with: Read Only but with Borders

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, lightninginput, read-only

I have a Lightning component with a form. This form has some fields as Read Only and some others editable. I use Lightning input with the property readonly.
The issue is that on the ones that are readonly = "true", i want to keep having the "border", just as in non-read only. Is there a way to achieve that?
For example in the below picture, i would like the value of DOY Code (1101) to be within a field "border" just like the field above.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that would be to use the `disabled` attribute. However, this will have other side effects, such as graying out the box and displaying the  mouse cursor.

```
<lightning-input label="Demo" value={displayValue} disabled></lightning-input>
```

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/6v3qUU6EAFujk2W1fR5x/src/app.js).